# Check the version of an app installed on iPad

Tags: ipad, applications

Is there anyway to check the version of an app installed on a iPad without connecting back to iTunes on my desktop / laptop?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

iOS provides a list with all installed Apps and their memory usage. Tapping on any App on that list will, besides giving you the option to delete it, display the name, the **version**, its size and how much memory it's using.

The path to access this list has changed through the iOS versions:

**iOS 11:** Settings / General / iPad Storage

**iOS 9:** Settings / General / Storage and iCloud usage / Manage Storage

**iOS 8:** Settings / General / Usage / Manage Storage

**iOS 7:** Settings / General / Usage